# How to bind UISwitch to UIButton enable in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a `UISwitch` that needs to be selected in order to continue onto the next form screen. So I would like to bind the `UISwitch` selected to the `UIButton` enabled. I just can't get this sample going.

Here's what I'm trying but doesn't compile:

```
let termsValidation = termsSwitch
    .rx_selected
    .shareReplay(1)

termsValidation
    .bindTo(signupButton.rx_enabled)
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

What's the correct way to get this to work in RxSwift and RxCocoa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `rx_value` rather than `rx_selected`.

Answer (score 5):

```
    let termsValidation = termsSwitch
            .rx.value
            .shareReplay(1)

    termsValidation
        .bind(to: signupButton.rx.isEnabled)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```